# How to make custom 'any object' Cascade (.xml) for opencv-python?

Tags: opencv, python

I want to make a haar cascade so that I can use it to detect a object in opencv-python.For eg, I want to detect a watch. I tried making a cascade using cascade trainer gui but it isn't giving me expected results.

Comment: so if I understand correctly you want to use the Haar cascade feature extractor  on custom objects?

Comment: I want to make a haar cascade about my watch so that i can use it in my python code to detect watches in a picture.
(basically i want to detect a watch in a picture using haar cascade.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, before training, search through the internet. Maybe the object you want to detect has already been trained, so you don't need to train again.

For example, you want to detect a watch. The haar-file is available [here](https://gitlab.com/andaesa/classifyingimage/blob/master/classifywithcustomclassifier/watchcascade10stage.xml).

So I used the file whether it is working or not, the result is:

[image]

Code:

```py
import cv2

w_cascade = cv2.CascadeClassifier('watchcascade10stage.xml')

cap = cv2.VideoCapture(0)

while True:
    ret, img = cap.read()
    if ret:
        gray = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2GRAY)
        w = w_cascade.detectMultiScale(image=gray,
                                       scaleFactor=1.3                                        
                                       minNeighbors=50)

        for (x, y, w, h) in watches:
            cv2.rectangle(img, (x, y), (x + w, y + h), (255, 255, 0), 2)
            font = cv2.FONT_HERSHEY_SIMPLEX
            cv2.putText(img, 'Watch', (x - w, y - h), font, 0.5, (11, 255, 255),  2, cv2.LINE_AA)

        cv2.imshow('img', img)
        k = cv2.waitKey(0) & 0xff
        if k == 27:
             break

cap.release()
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

You can find other tutorial searching through the internet. For instance start with [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=ydSXgBZ1ybk)

Comment: Thanks a lot for the cascade file for watches.However, I want to make a cascade file.I checked the video you had given in the link. I had used the same software earlier but it is giving me wrong predictions.

Answer (score 0):

So the thing is Haar Cascade is not a detector or even a classifier. It is  a feature extractor IF you are going to use Haar Cascade you will use it in conjunction with SVM (support vector machines) for classification and then implement a sliding window to detect watches.
So the steps are a fallowed.
1  Extract a patch of images using sliding window.
2  pass it to SVM trained on Haar Cascade
3  Draw rect if prediction is true

I recommend this tutorial series https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial/.please do reach out to me if you still need help.

Comment: I didn't quite understand what you are trying to say.Also, https://pythonprogramming.net/haar-cascade-object-detection-python-opencv-tutorial
Also, how do we do this in windows ?